# Build custom output in for loop over object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a json object, but want to format the output into a variable.

```
var json =  [
   {
      "link-params": {
         "location_id": 1
      },
      "link-text": "United States"
   },
   {
      "link-params": {
         "location_id": 9
      },
      "link-text": "Florida"
   }
]

 for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
   var data = json[i]['link-text'];
 }

//output United States / Florida
```

I want the output like United States / Florida

Any idea how you do this in javascript? I am using angular.js

Comment: " str2.concat(str1) " function use

Comment: access JSON object with `json["link-text"]` and concatenate them.

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
data='';
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
   var str1 =  json[i]['link-text'];
   if(i !== json.length - 1) str1 += ' / ';
   data = data.concat(str1)
 }
```

Comment: The desired output is United States / Florida, while the above code output will be United States/Florida/

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `data` earlier to make it visible to all of the iterations of the `json` object, and then concatenate values to it rather than overwriting it every time.

```
 var data = '';
 for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
   data += json[i]['link-text'];
   if(i !== json.length - 1) data += ' / ';  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function DetailCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.json =  [
   {
      "link-params": {
         "location_id": 1
      },
      "link-text": "United States"
   },
   {
      "link-params": {
         "location_id": 9
      },
      "link-text": "Florida"
   }
];
  var data = [];
  var item = "";
  angular.forEach($scope.json,function(value,key){
         angular.forEach(value,function(v,k){
             if(k == "link-text")
               item = item +v+"/";
           });
            
      });
  data.push(item);
 console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DetailCtrl">
  
</div>
```

Comment: How would I access this in the view?  {{item}}  Basically I am using Ionic Framework trying to get the <ion-view view-title="{{var}}"> to update dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), and write code in more functional way as below,

```
json.reduce(function(html, link){
    return html + (link['link-text'] ? link['link-text'] + ( json.indexOf(link) != json.length - 1 ?  ' / ' : '') : '');
}, '');
```

Demo : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ashwinaggarwal/q2opLyn0/)